# File manager stuck in Tree View

Tags: nautilus, settings

Somehow I managed to set my file manager to tree view.  Can not find any way of returning it to the default.  No tree box to uncheck on any of the preference tabs other than to list all files or just folders.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

File Manager > Preferences > Visualization > (at the bottom) List View: Browse folders in a tree view (or something similar, I have it in another language) [uncheck]

Comment: I have 12.04 (the penguin).  There is no visualization heading on any of the tabs or within them.